# Angular 1: How to add directive to DOM from view controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

What is the recommended Angular way of adding custom directives conditionally? No google post or SO article has seemed to really answer my question.

The app allows the user to display and interact with customer information. In one view, the person can click on the order details, which makes an API call to return the data. If the order comes back as a certain type, I want to add an indicator to the already rendered sidebar. It seems like a pretty simple and common use case so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

I'm using Angular 1.4x, 
Angular Bootstrap

It is a big app but here is a contrived example of the relevant code:

sidebar.html - before API call:

```
<div>
 <a href="#/customer">Customer Info</a>
 <a href="#/orders" id="ordertype"></a>
 <a href="#/notes">Notes</a>
</div>
```

sidebar.html - what I want to have after API call:

```
<div>
 <a href="#/customer">Customer Info</a>
 <a href="#/orders" id="ordertype">
  <order-type-directive uib-tooltip="Phone Order" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="top"/>
 </a>
 <a href="#/notes">Notes</a>
</div>
```

main-controller.js

```
angular.module('app.main')
.controller('mainCtrl', function(){
 var vm = this;
 vm.orderType;
  ...
  vm.getOrderData(memberID)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.orderType = data.type;
      //This is where my question arises
    })
})
```

So I can make a directive:

```
.directive('orderTypeDirective', function(){
  ...
})
```

Or I can just do something like this:

```
var el = angular.element('#orderType')
.html('<span uib-tooltip="Phone Order" popover-trigger="mouseenter"></span>');
var aNewScope = $scope.$new();
$compile(el)(aNewScope)
```

But I feel like the above is ugly and hacky. As to *how* I insert it into the DOM after creating the element, the documentation and all googling assumes I already know how to do that.

For the directive option I've tried to use an `ng-if` but it doesn't update when the API call comes back and updates `vm.orderType`.

For the create-element option, I could do something like this inside an `if` block in mainCtrl:

```
 el.replaceWithEl(el);
```

But I know there must be a better, more "Angular" way and that I'm missing something glaring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe with a `ng-if` directive ? like:

```
<div>
 <a href="#/customer">Customer Info</a>
 <a href="#/orders" id="ordertype">
  <order-type-directive uib-tooltip="Phone Order" 
                        tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" 
                        tooltip-placement="top" 
                        data-ng-if="mainCtrl.orderType && mainCtrl.orderType.length>0"/>
 </a>
 <a href="#/notes">Notes</a>
</div>
```

Or you can put any other condition in your `ng-if` directive that maybe match well your case